# Windows reports lesser storage after removing Ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive, storage

Recently I installed Ubuntu by wiping my PC, and now I've reinstalled Windows 10 and (apparently) uninstalled Ubuntu.

The problem is that I have a 256GB hard disk (INTEL SSDSC2KW256G8L), but in:

- Windows Explorer,
- Properties of the disk in Device Manager,
- Disk Management,
- Disk Part

it shows only 3 partitions (with total sum of 238GB) and when running "list disk" it tells me that the only disk0 has 238GB too.

I tried extending the disk and volumes but it didn't help.

When I run CHKDSK it confirms that the total disk space is 238GB (0 bad sectors), I don't think it's a mechanical issue, since I noticed it ~3hrs after the reinstallation

I couldn't find any help online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing like disappearing of memory. It is all about calculations (Apparent Vs. Actual). Drives are marketed in terms of decimal. So, 256GB is in decimal, i.e. 256,000,000,000B while OS shows memory in terms of binary. Therefore,
256,000,000,000/2<sup>30</sup>=238.41GB.

You may like to read these threads:

- [256GB SSD showing 238GB no partitions - Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2163150/256gb-ssd-showing-238gb-partitions.html)
- [256Gb SSD HD only shows 238GB? - Dell Community](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/256Gb-SSD-HD-only-shows-238GB/td-p/4452407)
- [256GB SSD shows a maximum capacity of 229GB - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-hardware/256gb-ssd-shows-a-maximum-capacity-of-229gb/45c42a5a-3769-4f01-906a-9b62b7088914)